# How to make a jar file run on startup & and when you log out?

Tags: java, startup, services, logout

I have no idea where to start looking. I've been reading about daemons and didn't understand the concept.

More details :

- I've been writing a crawler which never stops and crawlers over RSS in the internet.
- The crawler has been written in java - therefore its a jar right now.
- I'm an administrator on a machine that has Ubuntu 11.04 .
- There is some chances for the machine to crash , so I'd like the crawler to run every time you startup the machine.
- Furthermore, I'd like it to keep running even when i logged out. I'm not sure this is possible, but most of the time I'm logged out, and I still want to it crawl.

Any ideas? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Just looking for the simplest solution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a easy way to do that using SysVInit. Instructions:

1. Create the start and the stop script of your application. Put it on some directory, in our example is:

   - Start Script: `/usr/local/bin/myapp-start.sh`
   - Stop Script: `/usr/local/bin/myapp-stop.sh`

   Each one will provide the instructions to run/stop the app. For instance the `myapp-start.sh` content can be as simple as the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   java -jar myapp.jar
   ```

   For the stop script it can be something like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Grabs and kill a process from the pidlist that has the word myapp

   pid=`ps aux | grep myapp | awk '{print $2}'`
   kill -9 $pid
   ```
2. Create the following script (`myscript`) and put it on `/etc/init.d`.

   `/etc/init.d/myscript` content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # MyApp
   #
   # description: bla bla

   case $1 in
       start)
           /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myapp-start.sh
       ;;
       stop)
           /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myapp-stop.sh
       ;;
       restart)
           /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myapp-stop.sh
           /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myapp-start.sh
       ;;
   esac
   exit 0
   ```
3. Put the script to start with the system (using SysV). Just run the following command (*as root*):

   ```
   update-rc.d myscript defaults
   ```

PS: I know that Upstart is great and bla bla, but I preffer the old SysV init system.

Comment: But how do the system will know what parameter will use? How to set to be the "start". Tried here and it did not work.

Comment: This works, but the command "service myapp start" do not exit the command.

Comment: Now how to use the start|stop|restart options in myscript ?

Comment: Also, even after doing the 3 steps, my jar is not running on startup.
Are you sure if we have to change permissions, or path or something like that?

Comment: @Codevalley, as I mentioned, this method is for the SysV init. To use service or other command you'll need to write a upstart job. But if you are going to do this, you should write a systemd one (since it is becoming the standard)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. But I had to make the last script ('myscipt' in your example) executable with this command: chmod 755 /etc/init.d/myscript . Otherwise update-rc.d command couldn't execute it.

Comment: save my day, I just forgot to `chkconfig myscript on`

Comment: I have `update-rc.d: error: myscript Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting`. So it also requires some headings like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/925337/522873)

Answer (score 6):

Yes! It is possible. :) **Upstart** is the way to go to make sure the service stays running. It has five packages, all installed by default:

- Upstart init daemon and initctl utility
- upstart-logd provides the logd daemon and job definition file for logd service
- upstart-compat-sysv provides job definition files for the rc tasks and the reboot, runlevel, shutdown, and telinit tools that provide compatibility with SysVinit
- startup-tasks provides job definition files for system startup tasks
- system-services provides job definition files for tty services

The learning is very enjoyable and well worth it. Upstart has a website: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Comment: From the Upstart website, as of 2019: **"Project is in maintaince mode only. No new features are being developed and the general advice would be to move over to another minimal init system or systemd"**

Answer (score 2):

3 quick suggestions...

1. Create a **S**tart script in `/etc/rc3.d` (multiuser console mode) with corresponding **K**ill scripts in `/etc/rc.0` and `/etc/rc6.d` to kill your Java program in a controlled way when the system powers down (runevel 0) or reboots (runlevel 6) See [An introduction to Runlevels](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/212).

   You might be able to start your Java app in runlevel 2 (rc2.d) but, as a crawler, it will need TCP/IP. So make sure your networking service is available/started in your runlevel 2 beforehand. Networking is definitely up in runlevel 3.

   `/etc/init.d` contains all the actual start/kill scripts. `/etc/rcN.d` directories just contain links to them, prefixed with S or K to start or kill them respectively, per runlevel N.
2. A process run by `crond` should persist between logouts. Maybe add it to your crontab.
3. A process run with `nohup` should also persist. See [nohup: run a command even after you logout](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/).

   ```
   $ nohup java -jar myapp.jar &
   ```

   By default, `myapp.jar`'s standard output will go to a file named `./nohup.out`, or `$HOME/nohup.out` if the former isn't writeable.

Comment: And when i logout , will it still run on background?

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware when making aplications with:

```
  update-rc.d myscript defaults
```

To have permissions 0755 and to use or get before your .sh the path.
Let's say your script is on /root/test.sh , you should first change to CD `/root/` before accessing `test.sh`.

So best way is to make a SH on init.d and there change the path to your `sh` and execute it in the start function.

Answer (score 0):

Simple startup scripts with Java version checking for Linux [auth-agent](https://github.com/tumakha/auth-agent/blob/master/src/assembly/bin-linux/auth-agent)
and Windows [auth-agent.bat](https://github.com/tumakha/auth-agent/blob/master/src/assembly/root/bin/auth-agent.bat)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `supervisord`.  Please see full details at http://supervisord.org/

You can also view more details here:

[Running an executable jar file when the system starts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779830/running-an-executable-jar-file-when-the-system-starts/852485#852485)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

Answer (score 0):

I prefer systemd service and this is a sample for Quarkus application startup service and this is like any java application.

1. go to `/etc/systemd/system`
2. create `Quarkus.service` file
3. fill the file like this example.

```
    [Unit]
Description=Quarkus Application
Wants=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target
After=remote-fs.target
Before=multi-user.target
[Service]
User=test
LimitNOFILE=102642
Environment="QUARKUS_MAILER_PASSWORD=password1"
Environment="QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=password2"
Environment="QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password3"
ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/java -jar /path/to/jar file/target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
Type = simple
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. type `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. `systemctl enable quarkus.service`
6. `systemctl start quarkus.service`

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/run-java-application-as-service)