# How to make a .jar file execute on ubuntu server 14 startup

Tags: java, startup, jar

How do i make my .jar file execute on startup because we have constant blackouts here and when the server starts up i want the server.jar to start as well.

Is there any simple way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `/etc/rc.local` file by doing:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

And in there type

```
java -jar /path/to/your/file.jar
```

Make sure this goes BEFORE the 'exit 0'

Comment: Hi ive done this already, it does not work.

Comment: does `java -jar /path/to/your/file.jar` normally work?

Comment: Yes, well the command i use while logged in with putty is       nohup java -jar /path/to/file/file.jar &    then it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Try adding that exact command to the file, and see if that works for you

Comment: Also same result doesn't work, because its a basic network app so when i run the command it works but doesn't start up.

Comment: As a diagnostic step, before the nohup... line add the line 'ifconfig'. Tell me if you have an IP and connectivity at that point. Also, consider some of the answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/99232/how-to-make-a-jar-file-run-on-startup-and-when-you-log-out?rq=1, particularly `upstart`

Comment: Yes there is connectivity ip 192.168.1.101 it's static set it myself.