# Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting

Tags: shutdown, systemd

I'm trying to check if [this](https://www.behnke.io/fedora-17-on-an-aspire-v5-571-reboot-on-shutdown/) solution would help me with auto restarting after shutdown.

But command `sudo systemctl enable haltusbpower.service` is followed by error:

> Synchronizing state of haltusbpower.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
>   Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable haltusbpower
>   update-rc.d: error: haltusbpower Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.

My `/usr/lib/systemd/system/haltusbpower.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=haltusbpower
Before=shutdown.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/haltusbpower.sh
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```

My `/usr/local/bin/haltusbpower.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/control;
        do echo on > $i
done
```

It has execute option:

```
karol@karol:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/haltusbpower.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 88 kwi 27 13:03 /usr/local/bin/haltusbpow
```

Why enabling haltusbpower doesn't work? And what followed error means? I don't understand where to look for errors.

Comment: I found my answer [in this forum thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Installed-Jira-and-Confluence-as-a-service-but-they-don-t-start/qaq-p/792134) Long story short I had my old System V (service) file in my `/etc/init.d` directory so the system was trying to resolve the legacy code as well

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At the top of your `/usr/local/bin/haltusbpower.sh` script add something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          haltusbpower
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Halts USB power...
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this?

Comment: "haltusbpower" should be replace with your service name.

Comment: @BugsBuggy here is the official manual for *LSBInitScripts*: https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message but it included a message about `missing LSB tags and overrides`.

I looked in htop and had multiple processes tailing the log from when I tested the service using `/usr/local/bin/./MyService.sh start` and `/usr/local/bin/./MyService.sh stop`. Once I killed these processes it was successful.

The start and stop test command was taken from http://www.jcgonzalez.com/ubuntu-16-java-service-wrapper-example

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to repost the comment attached to original question as an answer since it was resolved my issue.

I had started with a shell script `/etc/init.d/kafka` and was using that with a start and stop flag. I then wrote a SystemD unit file and placed it in `/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service`. Many systemctl commands such as `systemctl cat kafka` and `systemctl status kafka` show that the unit-file was detected as the latter `kafka.service` file, yet somehow old one in /etc/init.d conflicted with this. As soon as I removed it, I was able to enable the service.

I cannot find any documentation on this behavior.