# How to make jar file run automatically on system start

Tags: bash, java, autostart, startup-applications

I am fololowing [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99232/how-to-make-a-jar-file-run-on-startup-and-when-you-log-out) but this did not work for me .

My start up script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar AppDemo.jar
```

My stop script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Grabs and kill a process from the pidlist that was the word app

pid=ps aux | grep AppDemo | awk '{print $2}'
kill -9 $pid
```

Myscript for `init.d` is:

```
!/bin/bash
# AppDemo
#
# description: Start Jar on system boot

 case $1 in
    start)
    /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/AppDemo-start.sh
    ;;
    stop)
        /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/AppDemo-stop.sh
       ;;
        restart)
        /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/App-Demo.sh
        /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/App-Demo.sh
       ;;
    esac
    exit 0
```

this is now working for me. I don't know what I did wrong can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

To run a command/script at start/reboot you could also e.g. use a cronjob. 
Run

```
sudo crontab -e
```

choose an editor (e.g. `2` for nano)
And add a line like

```
@reboot <path/to/your/script.sh>
```

Note:
Anyway inform you first about environment variables etc because cron by default runs on a limited environment and you might need to add some paths to run your script correctly.

Comment: when i use sudo crontab -e  , command line show a msg "sudo: corntab: command not found
"

Comment: You have a typo there: it's `crontab` not `corntab`

Comment: when i run sudo crontab -e thw output is no crontab for root - using an empty one

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-4 [2]: ^C
 what to do next

Comment: As I said already in my answer you do what it says there. Select an editor of your choice e.g. `2` and press `enter` to edit the crontab